# Why does tangent have a period of $180$ degrees whereas sine and cosine have periods of $360$ degrees?

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

$\cos\theta = \cos\phi$ and $\sin\theta = \sin\phi$ give $\theta = 2n\pi + \phi$ ($n$ being any integer)

But dividing 2nd equation by 1st one gives $\tan\theta = \tan\phi$ which in turn reduces to $\theta = n\pi + \phi$ ($n$ being any integer).

Where am I wrong?

Comment: For the same reason that $(-1)^n$ has period $2$ over the integers, but $(-1)^n\cdot(-1)^n$ has period $1$.

Comment: @dxiv That comment takes a second reading to fully understand, but it's just the perfect answer.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think it out.

$\sin(\theta + \pi) = -\sin(\theta)$

$\cos(\theta + \pi) = -\cos(\theta)$

So $\tan(\theta + \pi) = \frac {\sin(\theta + \pi)}{\cos(\theta + \pi) } = \frac {-\sin \theta}{-\cos \theta} = \frac {\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = \tan {\theta}$.

====

So $\tan {\theta} = \tan {\phi}$

Means either $\sin{\theta} = \sin{\phi}$ and $\cos{\theta} = \cos{\phi}$ OR $\sin{\theta} = -\sin{\phi}$ and $\cos{\theta} = -\cos{\phi}$.

Which means $\theta = 2k\pi + \phi$ OR $\theta = (2k+1)\pi + \phi$.

Which means $\theta = n*\pi + \phi$.

Comment: It seems you are claiming that $a/b=c/d$ means either $a=c$ and $b=d$ or $a=-c$ and $b=-d$

Comment: No, I am not.  I am claiming that $\frac{\sin|\cos x}{\cos|\sin x} = \frac{\sin|\cos y}{\cos|\sin y}$ then $\sin|\cos x = \pm \sin|\cos y$.  That is clear as $\|sin x| < |\sin y| \implies |\cos x| > |\cos y|\implies |\tan x| < |\tan y|$

Comment: That's why I wrote “it seems”. ;-) The remark was needed, imo.

Answer (score 1):

If you know nothing about the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ except that they have period $l$ then you could deduce that $f(x) + g(x)$ and also multiplication and division of the two have period $l$ at most but you could not rule out a shorter period.  The period might be a submultiple of $l$.

In this case, you might say that $sin$ and $cos$ are "anti-periodic" with anti-period $\pi$.  In general, my "anti-periodic" would mean: $f(x + l) = -f(x)$.  Now, it should be obvious that multiplying or dividing two anti-periodic functions gives you a regular periodic one.  Also, it is obvious that if $f$ has anti-period $l$ then it has regular period $2l$ which might explain why it is not a common term.

Comment: A concept the OP may find useful is "periodic with **a** period k" means f(x+k) = f(x).  This is not to say k is the *only* period of f.    Obviously if k is a period of f, the mk will be a period.  If we don't specify **a** period and just say "with period k" it is understood that k is the smallest (non-zero) period.  Since sin and cos both have $2\pi$ as smallest period if follows that tan will have $2\pi$ as **a** period.  But there's nothing paradoxical that tan may also have a smaller period.  Your observation of "anti-period" explains why.

Comment: Yes. Maybe, I should have said that even if $l$ was the smallest period for $f$ and $g$ then simple combinations of them will have period $l$ but not necessarily smallest period $l$.  It could be any submultiple or the combination might be constant or zero.